# Django rest-auth: calling RegisterView from other viewset; sensitive_post_parameters didn't receive an HttpRequest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

In my application powered by django-rest-framework I use django-rest-auth and allauth to handle the user registration, etc. Everything works fine.

I have one API endpoint that handles users' testimonials. The idea is that if someone who has no account at my website is adding a testimonial, I want to automatically create an account for him/her (in case if an email was entered) and the welcome email should be sent, profile created, etc.

So from the viewset that handles adding a testimonial, I am calling RegisterView like this; this is POST:

```
from rest_auth.registration.views import RegisterView

class AddTestimonialView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = TestimonialSerializer
    queryset = Testimonial.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny, ]

def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    ................
    RegisterView.as_view()(self.request)
```

But I am getting an error:

```
AssertionError at /api/auth/testimonial/add/
sensitive_post_parameters didn't receive an HttpRequest. If you are decorating a classmethod, be sure to use @method_decorator.
```

Seems that I should create a custom class and override some method(s) of RegisterView, dispatch likely. But can't figure out what exactly should I do. In fact the request has no sensitive data at all, just email, name, testimonial text, etc. No passwords or tokens.

This is an original code from RegisterView @ rest_auth.registration.views:

```
sensitive_post_parameters_m = method_decorator(
    sensitive_post_parameters('password1', 'password2')
)

class RegisterView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer
    permission_classes = register_permission_classes()
    token_model = TokenModel

    @sensitive_post_parameters_m
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(RegisterView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_response_data(self, user):
        if allauth_settings.EMAIL_VERIFICATION == \
                allauth_settings.EmailVerificationMethod.MANDATORY:
            return {"detail": _("Verification e-mail sent.")}

        if getattr(settings, 'REST_USE_JWT', False):
            data = {
                'user': user,
                'token': self.token
            }
            return JWTSerializer(data).data
        else:
            return TokenSerializer(user.auth_token).data

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)

        return Response(self.get_response_data(user),
                        status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
                        headers=headers)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        user = serializer.save(self.request)
        if getattr(settings, 'REST_USE_JWT', False):
            self.token = jwt_encode(user)
        else:
            create_token(self.token_model, user, serializer)

        complete_signup(self.request._request, user,
                        allauth_settings.EMAIL_VERIFICATION,
                        None)
        return user
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: what is type is `self.request`?

Comment: @PawełKordowski I added more code, thanks

Comment: can you put `print(type(self.request))` above `RegisterView.as_view()(self.request)` in order to check type?

Comment: @PawełKordowski it's ```<class 'rest_framework.request.Request'>```

Comment: try `self.request._request`

Comment: @PawełKordowski I've tried, forgot to mention, sorry. Got another error: ```RawPostDataException at /api/auth/testimonial/add/. You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream```

Comment: This is POST by the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you just replace:

```
RegisterView.as_view()(self.request)
```

with

```
serializer = RegisterSerializer(data=self.request.data)
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
user = self.perform_create(serializer)
```

?